# How to automatically create mapping configuration for views from database?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I was able to get all my tables as Entities, but my views are not created.

Following the documentation, I used the following commands:

```
bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

Then :

```
bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

to create all my getters and setters.

How can I create all my Entities from views?

Comment: What sort of views are you looking for?  CRUD stuff?

Comment: It's the views we are using in databse. We are wanting to make entities from them.

Comment: I see.  I'm guessing you might have to create those entities by hand.  Just use the view name in place of the table name.  Using database views in PHP is not very common.  Never really understood why.

Comment: Thx, we will find another solution or ust create them by hand !